# Simple ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 1 in loop

Tags: loops, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a .data file containing lines of values. I partition them into separate values using the `split` method, then I initialize an `ArrayList` where I add the model items to the list. I had a while loop for this specific code here which looked like this:

```
while (inFile.hasNextLine() {
   // Do something
}
```

That didn't seem to work so I switched it to a `for` loop.

```
public MachineLearningInstance(File f) {


    try {

        int noOfRowsInData = 0;

        LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(f));
        try {
            lnr.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            noOfRowsInData = lnr.getLineNumber();
            //System.out.println(noOfRowsInData);
            lnr.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        irisData = new ArrayList<Iris>();

        // While there is another line in inFile.
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(f);

        for (int i = 0; i < noOfRowsInData; i++) {

            if (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
                // Store line into String
                String line = inFile.nextLine();

                // Partition values into separate elements in array
                String[] numbers = line.split(comma);

                // Grab values from that line and store it into a Iris ArrayList Item
                irisData.add(i, new Iris(i, numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2], numbers[3], numbers[4]));

            }
        }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

For some weird reason (and I bet it is a really simply reason I just can't see it) I keep getting the `ArrayListIndexOutOfBoundsException 1` when I run this piece of code. I'm guessing that my while loop keeps looping? I don't understand what the problem seems to be.

Is it possible that my `LineNumberReader` is not reading the number of lines properly? I don't think that is the case though. Most likely I am not declaring something correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this happened to solve my problem, I'm really tired and have no interest right now in finding out why but it fixed the issue lol:

```
for (int i = 0; i < noOfRowsInData - 1; i++) {

            if (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
                // Store line into String
                String line = inFile.nextLine();

                // Partition values into separate elements in array
                String[] numbers = line.split(comma);

                // Grab values from that line and store it into a Iris ArrayList Item
                irisData.add(i, new Iris(i, numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2], numbers[3], numbers[4]));

            }
        }
```

Supposedly `noOfRowsInData - 1` fixes it.